# Como comparar dois ArrayList e obter os valores compartilhados por ambos?

Tags: java, lista

Eu possuo duas classes, elas são:

Classe FiltroCidade:

```
public class FiltroCidade {

    private int idCandidato;
    private List<String> cidades;

    public FiltroCidade(){ }

    public int getIdCandidato() {
        return idCandidato;
    }

    public void setIdCandidato(int idCandidato) {
        this.idCandidato = idCandidato;
    }

    public void addCidade(String cidade) {
        cidades.add(cidade);
    }

    public List<String> getCidades() {
        return cidades;
    }    
}
```

Classe VagaEmprego:

```
public class VagaEmprego {    
    private String nomeVaga;
    private String cidade;

    public VagaEmprego() { }    

    public VagaEmprego(String nomeVaga, String cidade) {        
        this.nomeVaga = nomeVaga;
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getNomeVaga() {
        return nomeVaga;
    }

    public void setNomeVaga(String nomeVaga) {
        this.nomeVaga = nomeVaga;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
}
```

E possuo um `ArrayList` populado, ele é:

ArrayList vagas:

```
List<VagaEmprego> vagas = new ArrayList<>();
vagas.add(new VagaEmprego("Programador C", "Cruzeiro"));
vagas.add(new VagaEmprego("Programador Delphi", "Queluz"));
vagas.add(new VagaEmprego("Administrador", "Acre"));
vagas.add(new VagaEmprego("Programador Java", "Guaratingueta"));
```

E possuo varias cidades adicionadas no atributo `cidades` da minha classe `FiltroCidade`, veja:

```
FiltroCidade filtroCidade = new FiltroCidade();
filtroCidade.setIdCandidato(1);
filtroCidade.addCidade("Cruzeiro");
filtroCidade.addCidade("Gotham");
filtroCidade.addCidade("Acre");
```

Como posso obter as vagas onde as cidades são as mesmas do atributo `cidades` da classe `FiltroCidade`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Com **Java 8** você pode resolver utilizando expressão `lambda` para filtrar apenas os registros em que a cidade está contida dentro do `array` de filtros de cidade.

```
List<VagaEmprego> encontradas = vagas
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> filtroCidade
                .getCidades()
                .contains(p.getCidade()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

A partir do **Java 5** você pode utilizar o método de predicado.

> **Segundo o artigo [Filtrando resultados (Predicados) - Java 8](http://www.ocaminhodoprogramador.com.br/2014/03/filtrando-resultados-predicados-java-8.html)**
>
> ... Métodos que realizam a avaliação de elementos, são conhecidos como predicados, que no Java é representado pela classe Predicate e contem o método filter...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public interface Predicado<T> {

  boolean aplicar(T tipo);

  public static <T> Collection<T> filtrar(Collection<T> colecao, Predicado<T> predicado) {
    Collection<T> resultado = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T elemento : colecao) {
      if (predicado.aplicar(elemento)) {
        resultado.add(elemento);
      }
    }

    return resultado;
  }
}
```

E utilizando:

```
Predicado<VagaEmprego> predicado = new Predicado<VagaEmprego>() {
  public boolean aplicar(VagaEmprego vaga) {
    return filtroCidade.getCidades().contains(vaga.getCidade());
  }
};

Collection<VagaEmprego> encontradas = Predicado.filtrar(vagas, predicado);
```

---

Em **versões anteriores** você pode filtrar da seguinte forma:

```
List<VagaEmprego> encontradas = new ArrayList<>();

for (VagaEmprego vaga : vagas) {
  if (filtroCidade.getCidades().contains(vaga.getCidade())) {
    encontradas.add(vaga);
  }
}
```

Comment: "A partir do **Java 5**" => não foi erro de digitação? Deveria ter saído o 8 não?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não. A solução do Java 8 é a primeira. A segunda funciona a partir do 5 mesmo

Comment: Estava me referindo ao segundo parágrafo, o primeiro após o primeiro bloco de código e antes da citação, que você fala que pode "usar o método de predicado". Parece- me que você digitou do teclado numérico e acertou uma tecla abaixo do 8, mas não tenho certeza. Parágrafo na íntegra: "A partir do **Java 5** você pode utilizar o método  de predicado."

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não, é Java 5 mesmo. O método do predicado é o que eu descrevi logo abaixo deste texto, que funciona a partir do Java 5. O intuito é oferecer uma solução do 5 até a 7 e outro a partir do 8

Comment: Entendi agora, valeu. Uma coisa que não me ficou clara foi usar o método estático em interface, lembrava disso apenas no Java 8. Mas é trivial mudar para classe abstrata, confirmada a minha suspeita